# Regex Java First letter is not included in the right group?

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regex, and I can't understand the grouping in Java.
Currently my regex expression is

```
([^:]?)(?![email])(\w+[\. ]?\w+)\ ?\@[\. ]?(\w+\.?\w+)\.edu
```

My goal is the extract email addresses that come in various formats. An example of a line of string that doesn't work with this is:

```
To get on the vcode mailing list, please email engler@lcs.mit.edu.
```

My expression matches the correct string but

```
group(1) = e
group(2) = ngler
```

What I want is

```
group(2) = engler
```

It works for other strings such as href="mailto:balaji@stanford.edu">

Thanks for taking the time to help me out.
By the way I'm using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to help me out, it converts regex expressions into ones that java understands and shows you the groupings.

Thank you Affe

Answer:([^:]?)\b(?!(email))\b(\w+[. ]?\w+)\ ?\@[. ]?(\w+.?\w+).edu , I didn't know it was treated by characters, thank you.

Comment: Exactly what are you rules (abstractly) for deciding if something should be extracted? Just starting to read your regex, even the very first part (option non-colon?) makes me wonder what your criteria are.

Comment: Square brackets around the word "email" will make your regex capture one character in the set { e, m, a, i, l }.  I don't think that's your intent.

Comment: @Ben Lee I am trying to extract any string that contains an email in any abstract form. Such as jks at robotics;stanford;edu , I should be able to extract jks in one group, and robotics.stanford in another group. They come in many odd forms, its for a course I am taking. If you have any suggestions how I can improve my regex feel free to share, as I am still new and learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression [email] is a character class.  it matches any one of the letters e, m, a, i, or l.  It does not match the word "email."  That would just be email without the brackets.  That's why it picks up the e in engler.

Comment: @Miles Note that if you just remove the brackets `[]`, your regex will also include the word email in the overall match. That may be ok for what you need, but if you want to remove that as well, check my answer below which should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex instead:

```
([^:]?)(?<=email\s)(\w+[\. ]?\w+)\ ?\@[\. ]?(\w+\.?\w+)\.edu
```

I have changed the Negative Lookahead to a Positive Lookbehind because you want to assert that the characters `email` (with a space - i've added a `\s` for this) should precede the match.

I have also removed the `[]` brackets from `email` as this was matching any character from the word email and breaking your groups (as pointed out by @Affe and @phatfingers)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good description of capturing e-mail addresses with a regex can be found here: [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Parsing e-mail addresses is a pretty complex problem on which to learn regular expressions.  You might be well served to start with several simpler problems whose rules can be more easily articulated.